# Python-3.x time.sleep() wont work for print to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I would like to code a python that adds every x seconds a value.
But when I add the `time.sleep(x)` theres no output into the .txt file anymore.

And is there a way to stop the loop after a certain time?

Code:

```
f = open('Log.txt','a')
while True:
    print("This prints once a second.", file=f)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Recursively append text to file with the print and sleep functions:
```
import time

num = 1


def append_recursive():
    with open('Log.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(f"This prints once every {num} second.", file=f)
        time.sleep(num)
    append_recursive()


append_recursive()
```
Results in the file content of "Log.txt":
```
This prints once every 1 second.
This prints once every 1 second.
This prints once every 1 second.
This prints once every 1 second.
This prints once every 1 second.
This prints once every 1 second.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
import time
while True:
    with open('Log.txt','a') as f:
        f.write("This prints once a second.\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you want to stop after a given time:

```
import time
stop_after = 10 # seconds
start = time.time()

while time.time() - start < stop_after:
    with open('Log.txt','a') as f:
        f.write("This prints once a second.\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a context manager, and this works:

```
import time

while True:
    with open('Log.txt','a') as f:
        print("This prints once a second.",file=f)
    time.sleep(1)
```